# SKTextureAtlas how to load textures in order

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I've using a SKTextureAtlas (.atlas folder) to store the frames for an animation I'm using. I've numbered the frames like frame.1.png, frame.2.png, etc - there are 10 frames in total.

I noticed my animation looks horrible even though the frames previewed in my graphics program look great. I NSLoged out and found that it is loading the atlas in random order! I assumed it would at least follow the bundle file order. How do I get it to use the bundle order without sorting the array myself. Also do I put the @2x images in with the rest of them or do I create a separate atlas?

```
SKTextureAtlas *sleighAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"sleigh"];
NSArray *textureNames = [sleighAtlas textureNames];
NSMutableArray *sleighTextures = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *name in textureNames) {
    NSLog(@"texture: %@",name);
    SKTexture *texture = [sleighAtlas textureNamed:name];
    [sleighTextures addObject:texture];
}
```

Its printing out:

> 2013-12-04 09:56:54.407 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.3.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.407 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.6@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.408 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.8.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.408 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.5@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.408 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.4.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.408 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.9.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.409 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.4@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.409 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.9@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.409 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.5.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.410 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.1.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.410 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.3@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.410 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.6.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.410 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.8@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.411 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.2@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.411 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.2.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.455 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.7@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.456 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.1@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.456 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.10.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.456 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.10@2x.png
>   2013-12-04 09:56:54.457 Santa Game[41611:70b] texture: santaAndSleigh.7.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `textureNames` property contains texture names unordered. Instead of using fast enumeration use `for(;;)`:

```
for (int i=0; i < sleighAtlas.textureNames.count; i++) {
    NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"santaAndSleigh.%d", i];
    [sleighTextures addObject:[explosion2Atlas textureNamed:textureName]];
}
```

Though this method would probably not work if you put @2x images into `sleighAtlas`.

Comment: You can always divide the number of textures in half, so you'll only load the assets required for the device (retina or non-retina). 

`sleighAtlas.textureNames.count / 2`

Answer (score 3):

`func getTexturesByAtlas(_ atlasName: String) -> [SKTexture] {
       let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: atlasName)
       return atlas.textureNames.sorted().map { name in atlas.textureNamed(name) }
    }`

Comment: Usually a bit more explanation of your answer is helpful

Comment: This is the best answer, sadly the edit queue is full to properly display it and add a code comment.  Note it returns not only the name, but the `SKTexture`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to sort the array of textureNames first.

```
SKTextureAtlas *sleighAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"sleigh"];
NSArray * textureNames = [[atlas textureNames] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
NSMutableArray *sleighTextures = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSString *name in textureNames) {

    [sleighTextures addObject: [sleighAtlas textureNamed: name]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just sort the `textureNames` array using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` and something like `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`. Might get wonky with the @2x files included however.

Answer (score 0):

```
func loadFramesFromAtlasWithName(atlasName: String) -> [SKTexture] {
    let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: atlasName)
    var atlasTextures=[SKTexture]()
    for var x=0; x<atlas.textureNames.count; ++x{
         var texture = atlas.textureNamed(atlasName + "\(x)" + ".png")
         atlasTextures.append(texture)
        print(atlasName)

    }

    return atlasTextures
}
```

here is what i used with swift. I named my pictures inside the folder with the same name as the folder so the folder was labeled whale_swimming.atlas and the pic inside was named whale_swimming.png. this is necessary for my posted code to work

Answer (score 0):

```
var animTextures = Array<SKTexture>()
let animAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "anim")
for index in 1...animAtlas.textureNames.count {
    let frameName = String(format:"anim-%d", index)
    animTextures.append(animAtlas.textureNamed(frameName))
    print(frameName)
}
```